# Uncaught exception in event listener

Tags: java

I am explicitly throwing an exception in action performed method and not catching it , so EDT exception handler should catch it and ideally EDT should stop working but when I click on the button of the frame , EDT is again started . How a thread can be restarted?

Comment: Please clarify your question and show us the code you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EDT is a special case. It is restarted whenever it is stopped by an uncaught exception being thrown.

This is a good design because it ensures your entire GUI doesn't crash and burn because of an uncaught exception somewhere within, say, a button action.

Comment: Are you claiming that the EDT will actually shut down in case of an exception?

Comment: No, it has an uncaught exception handler that will prevent the thread from dying.

Comment: @Kayaman Do you have a reference that confirms the original thread doesn't stop? An exception handler does not indicate that the same original thread keeps running. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020757/java-does-the-edt-restart-or-not-when-an-exception-is-thrown.

Comment: True, it will not necessarily be the same thread instance. I'll make edits.

Answer (score 2):

When a thread throws an exception that isn't caught, [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) will be called. If it hasn't been set, the default uncaught exceptionhandler will be called. The handler will display a `stacktrace` and most likely be restarted, although the documentation doesn't specify what exactly are the steps taken.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448523/how-can-i-catch-event-dispatch-thread-edt-exceptions discusses the happenings of EDT exceptions.