# Should a JFrame be launched always in the EDT

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

My swing app has a main window which has sever buttons. This JFrame is launched in the EDT...

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame server = new JFrame();
            server.setVisible(true);
            server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                            //Do other stuff here
        }
    });
```

Each button can launch a separate JFrame.

I am not sure if I have to start a new EDT thread to launch each of these new windows?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do people run Java GUI's on the Event Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018165/why-do-people-run-java-guis-on-the-event-queue)

Comment: Nope. Not a duplicate, please read my question carefully and completely, not just the title.

Comment: *"Each button can launch a separate JFrame."*  (Shudder) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: _if I have to start a new EDT thread_ - there is exactly **one** EDT :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically when you are in a button handler (ie actionlistener) it is the EDT that is calling this. You can check this using SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem - each action handler is run on the `EDT`. So if you open new `JFrame` from such place there will be no problem.

If you were doing some work (e.g. calculations) in a different thread, then it is fine, but all the work that touches UI has to be done on the `EDT`. That's why we have `SwingWorker` and `invokeLater`.

Answer (score 2):

my answers are

- yes all changes, updates modifying, etc. should be done on [EventDispathThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- yes for creating a new Container should be created in [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

but

- not, you can prepare `JFrame` with its contents before, but for `EDT` there are two the most impotant methods,

  1. `JFrame#pack() // finalize & calculate used LayoutManager`
  2. `JFrame#setVisible(true) // display Container on the screen`
- `Each button can launch a separate JFrame.` don't do that, use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead, for switching betweens views, if you needed popup window then to create only one JFrame and another Container could be [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) only