# JLabel doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, window, jbutton, jlabel

I'm working on a program but my JLabel doesn't show up. My JButton works perfectly (it appears) but for some reason the JLabel does not appear. I have checked on internet but I Haven't found anything.

```
package com.hinx.client;

import java.awt.Color;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        createWindow();
    }       

    static void createWindow()
    {           

        //Create panel
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(null);

        //Build the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hinx - A marketplace for apps - Client ALPHA_0.0.1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Add the login button
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        login.setBounds(0, 342, 150, 30);

        //Create login label
        JLabel loginlabel = new JLabel("Login Area");

        //Create login panel
        JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel();
        loginpanel.setLayout(null);
        loginpanel.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 400);
        loginpanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        loginpanel.add(login);
        loginpanel.add(loginlabel);         

        content.add(loginpanel);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a `layout` for your `panel`. Per example :

```
loginpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

You can learn more about layouts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Here's what I get :
[image]

Comment: I cant change the location of the JLabel even by using setBounds();

Comment: *"I cant change the location of the JLabel even by using setBounds()"*  Don't use `setBounds()`!

Comment: Well I used setLocation() and it did not work. I really need to place the JLabel at a specific location.

Comment: @AndrewThompson People just don't want to accept fact that you have to use layout managers. This is not .NET!

Comment: *"I really need to place the JLabel at a specific location."*  If you really knew the size components need to be and how to place them, you could include that logic in a custom layout manager. But trust me, you don't.  You really just need to understand how to work with layout managers (+ layout padding, borders etc.) & how to nest them inside one another.  If the problem is the layout, your next question should focus on that.  Provide ASCII art of how the GUI should look.

Comment: I figured out how to place it to a specific location, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

> I have checked on internet but I Haven't found anything.

- JFrame is visible before JComponents (`frame.add(content);`) are added / created
- move code line `frame.setVisible(true);` (better everything about JFrame) to the end of constuctor

Answer (score 2):

1. Use layouts. [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) should be fine in this case. Do not call `setBounds()` and do not set layout as a `null`.
2. Add label and button on `JPanel`
3. Then add `JPanel` on `JFrame`
4. Call `pack()` instead of `setSize()`
5. Call `setVisible(true)` in the end.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are making setLayout `null`.

```
    JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel();
    loginpanel.setLayout(null);
```

Use this,

```
    JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel();
    loginpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Run the UI on the `EDT` instead of running on the main thread. Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018165/why-do-people-run-java-guis-on-the-event-queue).

Example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        Runnable r  = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createWindow();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
```